# GCC compiler flags: -lg2c -lgfortran

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction

Does anyone have any information on the GCC flags: -lg2c or -lgfortran? I can't find any documentation on the web and I'm interested in what these commands are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-lXYZ` specifies that GCC should link against a library called `libXYZ`.

See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options.

Comment: Actually, it would link against a library named either `libXYZ.so` or `libXYZ.a` (searched for in that order).

Answer (score 9):

-lg2c is for g77

-lgfortran is for gfortran (if gcc is later than 4.0)